# How to add CSS styles via JavaScript at runtime?

Tags: javascript, css, styles

I have the following css rules defined in my `<style>...</style>` section:

```
<style>
    div[class*=col-] {border-right: 1px solid #ccc; border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;}
    div[class*=col-]:first-child {border-left: 1px solid #ccc; border-top:1px solid #ccc;}
</style>
```

How can add these rules to the page at runtime using JavaScript only (no jquery).

Comment: create a style element (`document.createElement`), add the content to this element, add the element to the DOM (`document.head.appendChild`)